# Opaque reference instead of PImpl. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, idioms

> The PIMPL Idiom is a technique for implementation hiding in which a public class wraps a structure or class that cannot be seen outside the library the public class is part of. This hides internal implementation details and data from the user of the library.

**But is it possible to implement the same making use of reference?**

MCanvasFont.h

```
namespace Impl {
    class FontDelegate;
}

class MCanvasFont
{
public:
    MCanvasFont();
    virtual ~MCanvasFont();

protected:
    // Reference count
    long m_cRef;

    // agg font delegate
    const Impl::FontDelegate& m_font;
}
```

MCanvasFont.cpp

```
// helpers
#include "ImplHelpers/FontDelegate.h"

MCanvasFont::MCanvasFont()
: m_cRef(1),
  m_font(Impl::FontDelegate() )
{
    // constructor's body
}
```

P.S. This code compiles without any problems with G++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an error in your program, and it's in the constructor's initialiser list:

```
MCanvasFont::MCanvasFont()
: m_cRef(1),
  m_font(Impl::FontDelegate() ) // <--- BANG
{
```

The problem with `Impl::FontDelegate()` is that it constructs a *temporary* object. This won't outlive the constructor - in fact it's actually destroyed before entering the constructor body, as it's lifetime is that of the expression in which it appears. Thus your `m_font` reference is instantly invalid.

While you *could* initialise it using a manually allocated object (`*new Impl::FontDelegate()`) you're in undefined territory if that allocation fails unless you have exceptions enabled in your runtime. You'll also still have to `delete` the object in your destructor anyway. So the reference really doesn't buy you any advantages, it just makes for some rather unnatural code. I recommend using a const pointer instead:

```
const Impl::FontDelegate* const m_font;
```

**EDIT:** Just to illustrate the problem, take this equivalent example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    B() { std::cout << "B constructed\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "B destroyed\n"; }
};

struct A
{
    const B& b;
    A() :
        b(B())
    {
        std::cout << "A constructed\n";
    }
    void Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::Foo()\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A destroyed\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.Foo();
}
```

If you run this, the output will be:

```
B constructed
B destroyed
A constructed
A::Foo()
A destroyed
```

So `b` is invalid almost immediately.

Comment: If allocation fails, you get an exception, so there are no issues there. (barring the usual exception-in-constructor issues)

Comment: One can use a singleton pattern to allocate an object statically. It's GetInstance would return a reference to a static object.

Comment: The temporary's lifetime is actually extended to cover the constructor's body; but as you say, it certainly doesn't cover the object's lifetime.

Comment: @MikeSeymour hmm, GCC seems to disagree - when I run the example with the logged constructor/destructor, the temporary is destroyed before the constructor's body.

Comment: @Hurkyl true, though many disable exceptions in which case new just returns NULL.

Comment: @pmdj: "I recommend using a const pointer instead:". And I recommend using [std::unique_ptr](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-library#unique-ptr) and not dealing with raw pointers and manual resource handling, unless there is a very good reason to.