# Why the reference member that initialized from temporary is still readable?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)
>   [C++ constructor: garbage while initialization of const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138987/c-constructor-garbage-while-initialization-of-const-reference)

This question is directly related to another question that I've asked a time ago: ["Opaque reference instead of PImpl. Is it possible?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784281/opaque-reference-instead-of-pimpl-is-it-possible).

Let's say we have a class with a reference member of some other class which is initialized to a temporary variable in a constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    B(int new_x = 10) : x(new_x) { std::cout << "B constructed\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "B destroyed\n"; }

public:
    int x;
};

struct A
{
    A()
    : b( B(23) )
    {
        std::cout << "A constructed\n";
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::Foo()\n";
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A destroyed\n";
    }

public:
    const B& b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.Foo();
    cout << "x = " << a.b.x << endl;
}
```

When I run the code above, the output is:

```
B constructed
B destroyed
A constructed
A::Foo()
x = 23
A destroyed
```

It seems that even if temporary is destroyed so the reference member should be invalid, the integer field of the reference member is still readable. Why does it still work?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. There is no "why".

Comment: The memory still contains the value `23`. See [Can a local variable be accessed outside its scope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/597607)

Comment: This outstanding answer by Eric Lippert: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) answers your question as well. Voted to close as a dupe.

Comment: Add a couple of function calls in between and you might get some garbage...

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour.  It so happens in your case that the memory previously occupied by the temporary `B` is not overwritten before you reference it.  Next time you run the program, anything could happen.

Note that the superficially similar

```
const B &b = B();
```

does have defined behaviour; the lifetime of the temporary `B` is extended through reference binding.  This only applies to reference variables, not reference members.

Answer (score 1):

If a reference is invalid, that doesn't mean it's unreadable. It means that it doesn't refer to a valid object. It may or may not refer to some piece of accessible memory; if it does, you may or may not find that the memory contains the remnants of whatever object used to be there.

To summarise, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The memory that has been allocated to the temporary `B` is now invalid, but it has not been put to any other use. That is why your read produces the value that was there the last time. However, this is **undefined behavior**. Running valgrind should pinpoint the place of the error.

If you are wondering "how can it be", here is a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/335858) explaining what happens in a very similar situation.